# Need help on shell script option processing

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am struggling to make a script have this behavior:

- I want to pass options like this `./script -ab` is the same as `./script -a -b`
- And have this logic: "a & b -> c", "a & c -> c", "b & c -> c" (single option is function as normal)
- Also I want this script to fall back to a function (e.g help function) when calling the script without any option

This is some example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ${#} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Default function"
else
    while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
        case ${opt} in
        a) echo "a" ;;
        b) echo "b" ;;
        c) echo "c" ;;
        *) echo -e "Invalid option: ${@}" ;;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You've declared that all of your options require an argument (by writing `a:` instead of `a`), but in your examples you're not passing arguments. This is probably the source of most of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably most straightforward to just set flags for each of the options, and then after the loop check if the flags for both A and B are set and enable C if they are.

But you could model this as a bitmap with one bit each for A and B, and C being the state where both bits are set. So A=01, B=10, C=11 plus the default state with both bits cleared. (The states correspond to default=0, A=1, B=2, C=3 in decimal or hex.) Then just set the appropriate bits when the corresponding options are seen.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mode=0
while getopts "abc" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        a) mode=$(( mode | 0x01 )) ;; # set rightmost bit
        b) mode=$(( mode | 0x02 )) ;; # set leftmost bit
        c) mode=$(( mode | 0x03 )) ;; # set both bits
        *) exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

echo "chosen mode is $mode (0 = default, 1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c)"
```

Note that you mention `-A` and `-b` in the text, but your script has `a` and `b`. `getopts` cares about the letter case, so those aren't the same. Also
the colons in `getopts a:b:c:` mark the options as taking arguments, but you don't seem to need that.

Comment: I don't know really, but you likely want to use `0x04` rather than `0x03` for `c` if you're aiming to use `$mode` as a bitmask, to capture the various combinations of the three options in the values 0 through to 7.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, they said they want A+B to give C, and that happens with binary _or_ if A and B are distinct bits and C is the combination of the two. I definitely don't want C to be a third bit because then it won't _or_ together with either of the two others. (I can't edit the answer to show all the combinations right now, someone else may do it.)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't reading carefully enough. You're correct. I got too interested in the option processing and disregarded the required interaction between the options.

Answer (score 0):

*(Edited to handle new request in the question)*

You're very close.  Below is the kind of thing I've done.  It looks a bit complex at first, but it's a sequence of steps setting the defaults, parsing the command line, checking for bad option values or combinations, then script main routine after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# defaults for options
help=n
opt_a=1
opt_b=production
opt_c=0

# if no options from my user, print help message only
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then help=y; fi

# parse command line
while getopts ':ha:b:c' OPTION; do
  case "${OPTION}" in
     h) help=y            ;;
     a) opt_a="${OPTARG}" ;;
     b) opt_b="${OPTARG}" ;;
     c) opt_c=1           ;;
    \?) echo "$0: Error: Invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
     :) echo "$0: Error: option -${OPTARG} requires an argument" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# request for help overrides other actions
if [[ ${help} == 'y' ]]; then
  # put code here to print a USAGE message
  exit 0
fi

# check and error out on bad options from my user
# check -b:
case "$opt_b" in
  production) ;;
     staging) ;;
          qa) ;;
           *) echo "$0: Error: unknown argument -b \"${opt_b}\", exiting" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
esac

# script does its work starting from here
```

Invoking with `script-name -c -b qa` will parse the options `-b` and `-c` as expected, and `script-name -cb qa` will also work.

I gave only one example of checking the options (to keep the answer simple); normally there would be more code to check each option and respond to legal and illegal combinations of options.  I usually tuck those lines of code into a subroutine so they aren't in the middle of the script's main work flow.